# which one should complete first , select or update in postgreql database?

Tags: database, postgresql

If on ABC table update was running at the same point select was also started running on the same table,In postgresql, which will take first?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the situation and the question? There's no guaranteed answer to the minimal question you asked because everything can vary on size of insert and select, size of table, index situation, number of dead tuples, not to mention things like disk speed, i/o vs cpu, what's in cache, etc, etc.

Comment: Suppose i have a table which will take 10 minutes to update on certain predicate and 2 minutes to select on certain predicate.so i have started an update ,after 2 minute another user started his select query,in this case which will result first? either select or update? and also does update will take a lock and table and does not allow other user to do select and wait till update completes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I know what you're asking.

When you update something, it's not visible to anything else until you commit that transaction. When you update something and it takes a while, it should not block any selects on that same stuff.

So if you start your 10-minute update, and then someone starts their 2-minute select, they will see the old data, and will not be blocked. The update will continue without interruption. After the update completes, if someone starts the 2-minute select again, they will see the new data.

Does that answer your question?

---

The reason for this, in case you're interested, is that postgresql uses [MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control). Essentially that means that when you update rows, new copies of those rows are written. On the new copies, postgres indicates what transactions can see the new data. The old data sticks around, and also has information about what transactions can see it.

When you select, postgres checks the table, and looks to see which of those rows are visible to you in your current transaction. It only returns rows you can see.

When there are no more transactions that can see a row, postgres knows it can be deleted, and will reclaim that space.

Comment: Thank you.it answers my concern.